# WPF I can not get MouseMove event when the form AllowsTransparency=true

Tags: wpf, transparent

```
<Window x:Class="mtWPFScratchPad.DeskForm"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="mtWPFScratchPad"  AllowsTransparency="True" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded"  WindowStyle="None" Background="#00FFFFFF" Closing="Window_Closing"  Topmost="True" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">
<InkCanvas Name="inkCanv"   Background="Transparent">

</InkCanvas>
```

When i set the window should be transparency.I can not get the mousemove Event.
How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you set `InkCanvas` color to any other than `Transparent` like `White`.. Setting `Background` property of will solve this issue..

Comment: I need to build a application. It can drawing on the Desk. and it can click shortcut on the desk.So i need a panel i can drawing on this, and it can transpanret

Answer (score 0):

[image]
    If you set Both transparent it's not working You have to change ink canvas color or either change Allow transparency = false

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" AllowsTransparency="True"  WindowState="Normal Loaded="Window_Loaded_1" WindowStyle="None" Background="#00FFFFFF" Closing="Window_Closing_1" Topmost="True" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove_1" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid>
        <InkCanvas Name="inkCanvas" Background="White">

        </InkCanvas>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I need to build a application. It can drawing on the Desk. and it can click shortcut on the desk.So i need a panel i can drawing on this, and it can transpanret

Comment: can you describe more in question. so i can understand both transperant is not possible.